# What are the rules of Minecraft Mod questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

We have had quite a few questions regarding Minecraft mods, some along the lines of "Mods crashed. Halp". A lot of these get closed, which is understandable. *Unmodded* Minecraft crashes are hard enough to solve without the right information, so modded Minecraft packs make it infinitely more difficult.

However, (I can't recall the specific question where I read this) I saw a comment saying "We don't allow modded Minecraft crash questions" (for the above mentioned reasons, among others). Though I have seen plenty of questions involving forge crashes, specific mod crashes, etc.

So what *precisely* do we allow in terms of Modded Minecraft support?

Comment: We don't support crash questions because of this meta: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no - We allow generic mod questions because of this meta: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1130/are-questions-about-mods-on-topic?rq=1